# Why does changing search keyword break my simple Puppeteer scraper?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, puppeteer

### The Program

This is a simple web scraper in NodeJS using **[Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)**. I want it to look for "**Jeep Wranglers**" and output the results in JSON.

#### IPhone X vs. Jeep Wrangler

When I run the code using the keyword "IPhoneX", it works perfectly! I am presented with the following results:

> URL resolved for this query:
> https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/jacksonville/search/?query=IPhone%20X

```
[
  {
    itemTitle: 'iPhone X (64gb) Unlocked',
    itemPrice: null,
    itemURL: 'https://facebook.com//marketplace/item/660933184466809/',
    itemImg: 'https://scontent-mia3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/c0.2.261.261a/p261x260/95204129_555831935070812_4787210156310003712_o.jpg?_nc_cat=109&_nc_sid=843cd7&_nc_oc=AQlwXNEAvJyUsehdWQc3Sazu8yPFLt4-UenwazHfKoUHQgFk2Y0IMxFLNVOM9Ufkixk&_nc_ht=scontent-mia3-2.xx&oh=73a71c8d46087a03222be9d8ccec20e2&oe=5ED06145'
  },
  {
    itemTitle: 'iPhone Xs 64gb Unlocked Space Gray',
    itemPrice: null,
    itemURL: 'https://facebook.com//marketplace/item/235068041103141/',
    itemImg: 'https://scontent-mia3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/c0.29.261.261a/p261x260/94617759_1443663249148648_6414747198054989824_o.jpg?_nc_cat=105&_nc_sid=843cd7&_nc_oc=AQmCvaqKMfBLRiJGlN4xzNc5M8ppYEuLQDYZ6-FQalHWfPb0Wh1VMdyPzFmiHLbEyZI&_nc_ht=scontent-mia3-2.xx&oh=854a856849d7323229b1b5b927245811&oe=5ECE0F49'
  }
]
```

but... when I change the keyword to "jeep wrangler", which is the result I need, I am presented with this...

> URL resolved for this query:
> https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/jacksonville/search/?query=jeep%20wrangler

```
Selector error.
undefined
```

I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, but no luck.

### The Source

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const getItems = async searchTerm => {
    //{headless: false, defaultViewport: null} --> put this in launch() method below as parameter for developtment purposes --> opens up browser window
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, defaultViewport: null});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(`https://facebook.com/marketplace/search/?query=${encodeURI(searchTerm)}`);

    const itemList = await page.waitForSelector('div > div > span > div > a[tabindex="0"]')
    .then(() => page.evaluate(() => {
        const itemArray = [];
        const itemNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('div > div > span > div > a[tabindex="0"]');
        
        itemNodeList.forEach(item => {
            const itemTitle = item.querySelector('div > div > span > div > a > div > div > div > span > div > span > div[class="l9j0dhe7 stjgntxs ni8dbmo4"').innerText;
            const itemPrice = item.querySelector('div > div > span > div > a > div > div > div > div > span[class="oi732d6d ik7dh3pa d2edcug0 qv66sw1b c1et5uql a8c37x1j s89635nw ew0dbk1b a5q79mjw g1cxx5fr lrazzd5p oo9gr5id"').innerText;
            const itemURL = `https://facebook.com/${item.getAttribute('href')}`;
            const itemImg = item.querySelector('div > div > span > div > a > div > div > div > div > div > div > img').getAttribute('src');
            
            itemArray.push({itemTitle, itemPrice, itemURL, itemImg});
        });
        return itemArray;
    }))
    .catch(() => console.log("Selector error."));

    return itemList;

}

const initScraper = async() => {
    const items = await getItems('jeep wrangler');
    console.log(items);
}

initScraper();
```

Can anyone help me get this working? I have tried everything I can think of, and have no idea what is breaking this.

Thank you for looking.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one thing to do is to modify your catch so that you have an error parameter, and then you can print it out, which will give you more information like so:

`.catch((err) => console.log("Selector error: "+err));`

Comment: ok great idea. This is what I got:  Selector error: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:6:158
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:5:22

Comment: Well, it seems to be indicating that either of the two first item.querySelector statements is  not finding something that matches those long query selectors. Presumably that specific web page does not contain the info you are looking for.

Comment: yes, it was not loaded yet. When it loaded, the error disappeared. This issue resolved, but this poses another unrelated one. I am on it! thanks.